# rsync --copy-unsafe-links problem with a relative symlink (does not copy)

Tags: copy, command-line-interface, relative-path, rsync, symlink

When I use rsync with option `--copy-unsafe-links` it does not work when a symlink is relative. If a simlink is absolute it works as expected: copies content of the target instead of creating a broken symlink.

I have a dir structure in `/tmp`:

```
rsync-problem
├── dst
└── src
    ├── a
    │   ├── a-file
    │   ├── b-symlink -> ../b
    │   └── c-symlink -> /tmp/rsync-problem/src/c
    ├── b
    │   └── b-file
    └── c
        └── c-file
```

after running rsync:

```
rsync \
--copy-unsafe-links \
--links \
--recursive \
/tmp/rsync-problem/src/a \
/tmp/rsync-problem/dst
```

I get a broken relative symlink: `b-symlink -> ../b` in the `rsync-problem/dst/a` dir and a properly converted absolute symlink into a file `rsync-problem/dst/a/c-symlink/c-file`

```
rsync-problem
├── dst
│   └── a
│       ├── a-file
│       ├── b-symlink -> ../b
│       └── c-symlink
│           └── c-file
└── src
    ├── a
    │   ├── a-file
    │   ├── b-symlink -> ../b
    │   └── c-symlink -> /tmp/rsync-problem/src/c
    ├── b
    │   └── b-file
    └── c
        └── c-file
```

man of rsync for --copy-unsafe-links:

> This tells rsync to copy the referent of symbolic links that point outside the copied tree.  Absolute symlinks are also
> treated like ordinary  files,  and so are any symlinks in the source
> path itself when --relative is used.  This option has no additional
> effect if --copy-links was also specified.

Does not state that this option has no effect when a relative symlink is encountered.

and if I understand correctly

> This tells rsync to copy the referent of symbolic links that point
> **outside the copied tree**.

```
/tmp/rsync-problem/src/b
```

is outside the copied `src` tree:

```
/tmp/rsync-problem/src/a
```

what am I doing wrong and how to make rsync convert relative symlinks into files as it does with the absolute ones?

Script to replicate the issue:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ue

mkdir -p /tmp/rsync-problem/dst

mkdir -p /tmp/rsync-problem/src/a
touch /tmp/rsync-problem/src/a/a-file

mkdir -p /tmp/rsync-problem/src/b
touch /tmp/rsync-problem/src/b/b-file

mkdir -p /tmp/rsync-problem/src/c
touch /tmp/rsync-problem/src/c/c-file

cd /tmp/rsync-problem/src/a
ln -sr ../b b-symlink
ln -s /tmp/rsync-problem/src/c /tmp/rsync-problem/src/a/c-symlink

rsync \
--copy-unsafe-links \
--links \
--recursive \
/tmp/rsync-problem/src/a \
/tmp/rsync-problem/dst
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is intended behavior. You even emphasized "outside the copied tree". The tree is `/tmp/rsync-problem/src/a` and `../b` is not outside of it.